# Draw one shape in another shape

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas, rectangles

First I will explain what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to achieve cropping functionality. For that, I am drawing one rectangle on canvas and then trying to draw heart inside rectangle. So If user minimize/maximize rectangle heart will also minimize/maximize.

Here is my code.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (mIsInitialized) {
        setMatrix();
        Matrix localMatrix1 = new Matrix();
        localMatrix1.postConcat(this.mMatrix);
        Bitmap bm = getBitmap();
        if (bm != null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(bm, localMatrix1, mPaintBitmap);
            // draw edit frame
            drawEditFrame(canvas);
        }
    }
}

private void drawEditFrame(Canvas canvas) {

        mPaintTransparent.setFilterBitmap(true);
        mPaintTransparent.setColor(mOverlayColor);
        mPaintTransparent.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        Path path = new Path();
        path.addRect(mImageRect.left, mImageRect.top, mImageRect.right, mImageRect.bottom,
                Path.Direction.CW);

        drawHeart(mFrameRect.centerX(), mFrameRect.centerY(), path);
        canvas.drawPath(path, mPaintTransparent);
    }

private Path drawHeart(float width, float height, Path path) {

    // Starting point
    path.moveTo(width / 2, height / 5);

    // Upper left path
    path.cubicTo(5 * width / 14, 0,
            0, height / 15,
            width / 28, 2 * height / 5);

    // Lower left path
    path.cubicTo(width / 14, 2 * height / 3,
            3 * width / 7, 5 * height / 6,
            width / 2, height);

    // Lower right path
    path.cubicTo(4 * width / 7, 5 * height / 6,
            13 * width / 14, 2 * height / 3,
            27 * width / 28, 2 * height / 5);

    // Upper right path
    path.cubicTo(width, height / 15,
            9 * width / 14, 0,
            width / 2, height / 5);

    return path;
}

private void setMatrix() {
    mMatrix.reset();
    mMatrix.setTranslate(mCenter.x - mImgWidth * 0.5f, mCenter.y - mImgHeight * 0.5f);
    mMatrix.postScale(mScale, mScale, mCenter.x, mCenter.y);
    mMatrix.postRotate(mAngle, mCenter.x, mCenter.y);
}
```

But heart is sticking at top left corner and not moving or minimizing/maximizing as per rectangle.

Here is current image for reference.

[image]

Please provide me hint or any reference.

**EDIT**  I am able to draw circle inside rectangle which minimize/maximize as per rectangle size and move as per rectangle move. But I am not able to do same with custom heart.  Here is code for circle.

```
path.addCircle((mFrameRect.left + mFrameRect.right) / 2,
                (mFrameRect.top + mFrameRect.bottom) / 2,
                (mFrameRect.right - mFrameRect.left) / 2, Path.Direction.CCW);
```

Here is image in which I am drawing circle in rectangle which I want to achieve same with heart too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The implementation be like you should retake the whole bitmap size(height, width) before resizing then max/min the size of that bitmap.

Comment: Bitmap size should be same, heart size should be increase/decrease according to size of Rectangle and postilion of heart should be inside rectangle.